# Consulta SQL que me devuelva todos los campos que no tengan null o estén vacíos

Tags: mysql

Quiero que una consulta con `MySQL` me arroje las filas que sean `!= NULL || != ""`.

```
SELECT ProductID, Name, Color
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product
```

Por ejemplo en este caso me muestre la fila:

```
WHERE ProductID != NULL || ProductID !="" && Name != NULL || Name != "" && Color != NULL || Color != ""
```

Pero obviamente mi tabla no tiene solamente 3 campos, tiene mas de 50.
Se puede hacer este tipo de consulta sin utilizar `WHERE`?
O de que forma se puede utilizar el `WHERE` sin tener que poner `nombre_campo != NULL || nombre_campo != ""`?

Comment: exactamente quieres que te arroje las filas donde ningún campo de esa fila sea NULL o vacio?

Answer (score 1):

No se puede, en las consultas deben nombrarse siempre los campos que se van a seleccionar, lo que podría hacer es al campo que seleccione ponerle un IFNULL() para que muestre un valor diferente en caso de que venga nulo:

```
SELECT IFNULL(N_CAMPO, 'ES NULO'),
IFNULL(N_CAMPO2, 'NADA') FROM TABLA1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede con `NULL` es que no funcionan los comparadores lógicos, para ello te recomiendo hacer uso de `IS NULL` para llamar filas que contengas el `NULL` o `IS NOT NULL` para las filas que no contengan `NULL`.

espero te sirva.

| nombre | apellido1 | apellido2 | edad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANTONIO PEREZ |  |  | 30 |
| LUIS LOPEZ |  | PEREZ | 45 |
| ANTONIO GARCIA |  |  | 50 |

Ejemplo de uso de `IS NULL`

```sql
SELECT * FROM personas WHERE apellido2 IS NULL
```

| nombre | apellido1 | apellido2 | edad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANTONIO PEREZ |  |  | 30 |
| ANTONIO GARCIA |  |  | 50 |

Ejemplo de uso de `IS NOT NULL`

```sql
SELECT * FROM personas WHERE apellido2 IS NOT NULL
```

| nombre | apellido1 | apellido2 | edad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LUIS LOPEZ |  | PEREZ | 45 |